# Python can't import pysmp on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation

I successfully installed `pysnmp` with `yoaurt –S pysnmp`, but when I try to execture a scipt with Python 2.7 which has `import pysnmp`, I get

```
$ python2.7 test_script.txt.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.txt.py", line 85, in <module>
    import pysnmp
ImportError: No module named pysnmp
```

any idea what is going wrong?

This might be too much, distracting oinformation, but my Arch Linux is in a VM and the company has severe restrictions on internet access from the VM. Both `pacman` and `pip` errored, but `yaourt` was successful

```
packages (1) pysnmp-4.3.1-1

Total Installed Size:  2.50 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking keys in keyring        [##########################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity      [##########################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files           [##########################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts     [##########################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space   [##########################] 100%
(1/1) reinstalling pysnmp             [##########################] 100%
```

Comment: I never use Arch but i think you can search the installed package path (rf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681578/how-to-find-where-a-package-is-installed-by-pacman), then use `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)` to know your python's current search path. Then you will know the search path doesn't included your package path.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -E -- pacman -S python2 python2-pyasn1
yaourt -S python2-pysnmp
```

The -E on `sudo` uses the same enironment, which was necessary for me to get through the company's firewall.  Omitting it causes a new process to be launched, which did not have network access.  D'oh!